# Sonar code coverage satisfy a condition using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to increase code coverage of my project and facing challenge in making my Unit test case to reach else block in the below code `(#def)`

```
 Future<List<String>> myList = this.getSomeDetails(mobileNumber,user);
 myList.onComplete( result -> 
 {
    if(result.succeeded())
    {
          List<String> mobileList  = result.result();
          if(mobileList.isEmpty()){
           //some code #abc
          }
          else{
            //some code #def
         }
    }
});
```

This is what I have tried in my UT but somehow it still returns true and the else block is not executed. Any idea how do i cover the else block through my UT?

```
    List mockedList =Mockito.mock(List.class);
    Mockito.when(mockedList.isEmpty()).thenReturn(false);
```

Comment: don't "mock the list" (you can use a real one), but "mock"/setup `this.getSomeDetails(mobileNumber,user)` to return the expected `Future` (also no need to mock the "future" with CompletableFuture.completedFuture(...))

Answer (score 0):

I assume your "result" is created inside onComplete().

If this is the case, you can not mock it unless the "production code" of the result is externalized. (i.e. Into an injected factorys)

But this condition looks pretty easy to achieve. It looks like, you simply have to run your test with at least 1 value in the list (to reach that else branch).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But in my case , this.getSomeDetails() is a private method. So i can't mock it.  And i'm using mockito ( don't want to use powermockito to mock private method)